# How to get another component value in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

From this component, I will send data to another component

```
function SearchBox() {

    const [keywords, setKeywords] = useState('')

    return (
        <div className="form-group has-feedback">
        <Form >
            <Form.Control
                type='text'
                name='q'
                onChange ={(e) => setKeywords(e.target.value)}
                className = ' ml-sm-5 mt-4 p-3 mb-1 ml-2 Form-control'
                variant="light"                
            >
           
            </Form.Control>

             <Button type='submit' className='ps-5 pt-1 pb-1 mt-3 search-button' 
           variant="light">
             <i class="fas fa-search" variant="info"></i>
            </Button> 
            
        </Form>
        </div>
    )
    
}

export default SearchBox
```

I want the above component's keywords value to get below this component

```
function HomeScreen() {
 here I need value from above component 
}
```

Comment: I would suggest, read more about react and how it works. If you read it you will get your answer yourself

Comment: There are two ways to do this: either you use a store like redux, mobx, or zustand and feed both components from the same store. Or you identify a common ancestor and lift the state up to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain the `keywords` state in the `HomeScreen` component itself, rather than having it in the  `SearchBox`. Then pass down the `setKeywords` as a prop to the `SearchBox` and set it from the `onChange`:

```
function HomeScreen() {
 const [keywords, setKeywords] = useState('');
 return <SearchBox onSearch={setKeywords}/>;
}
```

Refer this design pattern [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)